# how to filter out rows in a dataframe whose value begins with a certain word

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

my df looks like this

```
    name                    type    info
90  Sizeer - Annopol 2      shoe    duplicate SIZEER 
91  InterSport - Arkadia    sport   duplicate INTERSPORT 
92  InterSport - Złota 59   sport   NaN
...
```

what i want to do is to remove all rows where the value in `info` column starts with the word **"duplicate"**. Its kinda tricky because this columns has not only string values, but also booleans. Moreover, the ones i wish to delete are not just 'duplicate', they have more text afterwards.

i tried doing this

```
duplicates = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    if str(df['info'])[i][:10] == 'duplicate':
         duplicates.append(i)
```

to get their ID's so i can delete them later, but it dosen't do anything. If i removed `str()` from `if str(df['info'])[i][:10] == 'duplicate':` there's an error

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

i also did this

```
dupli = df[df['info'] np.where('duplicate' in df['info'])]
```

but it's just a syntax error i dont really know how to do this properly :D

Comment: note: i cannot use pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates here.

Comment: `df[~df.info.str.contains('duplicate')]`

Comment: ```TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way for the word 'duplicate' at the start of the text:

```
df = df[~df.info.str.startswith('duplicate', na=False)]
```

If you want similarly but anywhere in the text:

```
df = df[~df.info.str.contains('duplicate', na=False)]
```

Comment: ```TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'```

Comment: please post here the result of df.dtypes

Comment: Not sure what your worte above

Comment: Try running before my code: df['info'] = df['info'].dropna()

Comment: as for the df.dtypes - they're all objects

Comment: Great!! Thought so... :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235692/discussion-between-adamdud-and-gtomer).